# Retrieve variable from sharedpreference class info to put into MySQL database (Android Studio using Volley)

Tags: java, php, mysql, sharedpreferences

I need to get the username from my login info and use it as a database entry for another table (for which I have created an API) but my code only puts NULL into the database instead of the actual value.

I am able to reflect the value in a text view but it still gets saved as a NULL value in my data base. I tried using many variants of the code available online, but those do not solve my problem.

Sharedpreference class contains the following:

```
  public String getUsername(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null);
}
```

I have created another class which is essentially a form to put data into database. In a new class (form) I am able to retrieve this using in a textview which works fine :

```
  textViewUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
  textViewUsername.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUsername());
```

BUT in the same class (form)  I am unable to put it in a String variable (it adds `NULL` value to the database:

```
  final String username = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUsername();
```

In:

```
  params.put("usename", username);
```

`
I am using volley to handle requests. I am using many other variables which I am retrieving from EditText in my input form, they are working just fine.

How can I retrieve the actual username and not a NULL value?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As i am not able to comment so i post it there. can you please add a check for SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this) return null or not. If it returns null then you have to assign same instance again in your activity in oncreate or onresume method.

Comment: should I get that as a toast?